# What do you call the rolling part of a combo lock?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the rolling part of a combo lock? The rolling part that allows you to enter combinations to unlock the lock? What is it called?

Comment: I would say that those parts are *turning*, not *rolling*.  It's a subtle difference, but "rolling" implies moving from one place to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia seems to call them *dials* and/or *discs*:

[Wikipedia *combination lock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination_lock)

> A combination lock is a type of locking device in which a sequence of symbols, usually numbers, is used to open the lock. The sequence may be entered using a single rotating **dial** which interacts with several discs or cams, by using a set of several rotating **discs** with inscribed symbols which directly interact with the locking mechanism, or through an electronic or mechanical keypad.